# Creating common base class implementing two generic interfaces?

Tags: c#, architecture

Is there a way to create a base class which implements both of the following two generic interfaces? This base class will then be inherited by "other" classes who can call methods from either of the two interfaces.

```
public interface IGenericRepositoryOne<E> where E : Entity
{
    void Save(E entity);
    void Save(List<E> entityList);
    E Load(Guid entityId);
}

public interface IGenericRepositoryTwo<D, E> where E : Entity
{
    void Save(D dto);
    void Save(List<D> entityList);
    D Load(Guid entityId);
}
```

Right now we have two separate Repositories which implement each of the interface separately:

```
public abstract class RepositoryOne<D, E> : IGenericRepositoryOne<D, E> where E : Entity {...}

public abstract class RepositoryTWO<E> : IGenericRepositoryTwo<E> where E : Entity {...}
```

And then there are classes which need to inherit either `RepositoryOne` or `RepositoryTwo`. It is at these class where I am looking to do some factoring, for example:

```
public class MessageDataTypeRepository : RepositoryTwo<MyEntityType>
{
    // here when I call the method Load() I want it for RepositoryOne implementation.
}

public class MessageDataTypeRepository : RepositoryOne<MyDTOType, MyEntityType>
{
    // here when I call the method Load() I want it for the RepositoryTwo implementation.
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about the <D, E> on the second one? I see no E in the member list.

Comment: Beyond that, what error did you run into when trying to implement both interfaces? Where did it give you trouble?

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: Yes, I need `E` also because there are other operations that use it, which are omitted above for brevity. And I updated my question to clarify further of what I am looking to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement both interfaces, and implement one or both using an [Explicit Interface Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  This allows you to have different implementations for each interface, if this is a requirement.

If this is not a requirement, simply implementing both should be straightforward, since both interfaces are effectively the same in terms of one generic type:

```
public class Repository<D,E> : IGenericRepositoryOne<D>, IGenericRepositoryTwo<D,E> 
    where D : Entity
    where E : Entity
{
    void Save(D dto) {}
    void Save(List<D> entityList) {}
    D Load(Guid entityId)
    {
          // Implement...
    }
}
```

---

Edit:

In response to your edited question, and your actual goals -

One option here would be to not use inheritance, but composition.  By using composition, you could make your "generic repository" class expose a single, meaningful interface, and internally build the appropriate repository.  It could then map through the methods to the appropriate repository as needed.  This would make your repository effectively an implementation of the [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to wrap either repository with a common interface.

Comment: Thanks for these comments. I updated my question further to reflect what I am trying to accomplish, could you please take a look at comment if something like that is possible otherwise I am looking at lots of duplication of the same repositories with little changes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible and it's called [Explicit Interface Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

You can implement methods from both interfaces with one method:

```
public void Save(D entity) { }
```

or separate implementation:

```
public void IGenericRepositoryOne.Save(D entity) { }

public void IGenericRepositoryTwo.Save(D entity) { }
```